# Why using Promise()?

Tags: javascript, promise

No matter how many tutorials I read, I still don't understand why I should use `Promise()`?!

Ok, let's make an example:

```
let cleanedUpMyRoom = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (true === true) {
    resolve(true);
  }
  else {
    reject(false);
  }

});

cleanedUpMyRoom.then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

This code returns either `true` or `false`.

```
function cleanedUpMyRoom() {
    if (true === true) {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}

console.log(cleanedUpMyRoom());
```

This code also returns either `true` or `false`.

Why would I use the first code, if the second code is shorter and easier to read?

Comment: You don't need it for *synchronous* operations that will complete immediately such as what you have shown Whole different story for *asynchronous* code that you have no idea when it will complete

Comment: Well, in your example, there's no reason to use a Promise. But let's say `cleanUpMyRoom` called a third party web API `http://didyouclean.com/api/yourroom` and you needed that answer back before you continue, then that's when you'd need a Promise. You can learn more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: You should use promises only for asynchronous code. Your example is not asynchronous.

Comment: Seriously?  In ALL you say you've read about promises, you never once read that promises are for managing ASYNCHRONOUS operations, not for use with synchronous operations like you show?  You really better read some more.  Promises simplify asynchronous operations.  They do not simplify synchronous operations and there is generally no reason to use them with synchronous code.

Comment: While it's not generally necessary or helpful to use promises in the synchronous case, one could still imagine using them for a case where a function can contain optionally asynchronous operations... or even for a synchronous function that one wants to behave as (or be interchangeable with) an asynchronous version.  Further, I don't think the down-voting is warranted- this might be a generally helpful question to people unfamiliar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As several people have pointed out, promises are typically used to serialize asynchronous operations.  The idea was developed as an alternative to nested callbacks, and what people have often referred to as "callback hell".  E.g. something with callbacks like:

```
asyncFn1(
          function(result1){
                            asyncFn2(result1,
                                     function(reult2){
                                        asyncFn3(result2)}
                                     )}
         )
```

can be rewritten using promises like:

```
asyncFn1()
.then(function(result1){asyncFn2(result1)})
.then(function(result2){asyncFn3(result2))
```

For complex cases where there are both success and failure handlers and functions depend on the results of other asynchronous operations, this can simplify the logic and greatly improve readability.

To look at your `cleanedUpMyRoom` example, a more common implementation would be to write:

```
cleanUpMyRoom = function(){
   cleanPromise = new Promise();

   startCleaning(/*on success*/ function(){console.log('Room cleaned!');
                                           cleanPromise.resolve()},
                 /*on failure*/ function(){console.log('Room cleaned!');  
                                           cleanPromise.resolve(result)})

   // or *alternatively* if it's just plain synchronous, 
   // var result = cleanIt()
   // if (result = "success")
   //   cleanPromise.resolve()
   // else
   //   cleanPromise.reject(result)

   return cleanPromise
});
```

then

```
cleanUpMyRoom.then(goGetIceCream(),contemplateFailure(result))
```

cleanUpMyRoom() always returns a promise that has a then function.  The *important* piece is that the function passed to `then` isn't called until the promise is resolved or rejected, and the result of the promise generating function is ready (whether synchronously or asynchronously).

Ultimately, a promise lets you chain together operations whose results may not be available in the synchronous procedural code so that nothing is called until the available, possibly asynchronous (like network requests), preconditions are met, and you code is able to manage on to other events in the meantime.

Take a look at this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

You also might be interested in the upcoming (ES2017) `async/await` syntax which is becoming popular and handles many asynchronous situations without explicitly using promises at all:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is an event driven language. In your short example, you are correct that using a promise would be pointless. In a more complex situation, say an AJAX request to the server, the code won't execute immediately.

Javascript will not work by simply returned the value as other imperative languages like python or java. The promise is advantageous by not blocking the main thread, and the code will begin running once the promise has been fullfilled. It makes javascript a great language for managing short spurts of activity through the event abstraction.